# Оптимизация функции

Tags: python, scipy

Необходимо найти минимум функции. 
Ранее для решения таких задачи использовал: scipy.optimize.fmin и меня все устраивало. Сейчас проблема состоит в том, что функция мало чувствительна к небольшим изменениям.
Из библиотеки scipy выбрал метод COBYLA, в нем можно установить первоначальный шаг на котором появляются изменения функции ('rhobeg': 50).

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x})  
a = minimize(lambda fit_params: 
                 optimization_function(fit_params), 
                 fit_p, method='COBYLA', 
                 options = {'rhobeg': 50}, 
                 constraints = cons)
```

Но данный метод работает не всегда корректно. Вот пример значений функции, которые он находит(только последнюю часть представил):

```
score:  [57.62744237]
score:  [57.62715163]
score:  [57.62705163]
score:  [10058.48725319]
score:  [57.62700163]
score:  [10058.48725319]
score:  [57.62700163]
score:  [10058.48725319]
```

В итоге получаем минимум:

```
fun: 10058.487253193078
   maxcv: 5.048099455931486e-31
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 69
  status: 1
 success: True
       x: array([ 4.94999747e+01, -5.04809946e-31, -5.04809946e-31])
```

То есть значения на последней итерации. Хотя до этого он находил гораздо более подходящие значения функции. Можно ли как то исправить эту проблемы в методе COBYLA или же стоит поискать другой способ? Может кто подскажет какой метод можно попробовать?